Display text instead of footnote marker
I am using footmisc  package with the following options :
\usepackage[norule,flushmargin,hang,para]{footmisc}
I would like to specify myself, for some footnotes, the text to appear instead of the footnote marker (both in the main text and in the footnotes). In other words, I would like to be able to write something like
\footnote[text instead of a footnote marker]{footnote content}
It is important to me that the resulting modified footnote would still be compatible with the footmisc package options.
Do you know how to do ?
Thanks !
For a minimal working example :
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[norule,flushmargin,hang,para]{footmisc} 
\begin{document}
azerty\footnote[10]{text}
\end{document}

I would like that some text, say "super", display instead of the footnote marker (10) just by writing something like
azerty\footnote[super]{text}

Thanks

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Welcome. // Please EDIT your question and move the code from your comment to your question. Makes it much easier to follow. Thank you

As usual, ChatGPT is not reliable. The suggested code is uselessly complicated and it adds unwanted spaces.
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\customfootnote}{o+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{#1}% Use custom text if optional argument is provided
  }%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}% just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

azerty\customfootnote{standard text} % Uses standard numbering

azerty\customfootnote[super]{custom text} % Uses "super" as the marker

azerty\customfootnote{standard text} % Uses standard numbering

\end{document}



Thanks a lot ! I accepted your answer rather than mine.

So, I asked GPT4o, and I post here the answer, that worked well for me.
It could be useful for the others:
The solution was simply to rewrite the footnote command as the following
% Custom footnote command with optional argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\customfootnote}{O{}+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifstrempty{#1}
    {\renewcommand\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}} % Use standard numbering if no optional argument
    {\renewcommand\thefootnote{#1}} % Use custom text if optional argument is provided
  \footnote{#2}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}
    {}
    {\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}} % Prevent incrementing the counter if custom text is used
  \endgroup
}

and the usage is :
\begin{document}
azerty\customfootnote{standard text} % Uses standard numbering
azerty\customfootnote[super]{custom text} % Uses "super" as the marker
\end{document}

